# Custom django form fields

Tags: django

I am trying to get if required "*" within lable tag. Somewhat close to this

```
<label for="id_name"><strong>Name</strong> <em>*</em></label>
```

With label_tag

```
{{ field.label_tag }}
```

it generates as

```
<label for="id_city">City</label>
```

this begins and closes label tag, how to insert "***" before closing

this hack seems to work,

```
<label for="id_{{ field.label }}">{{ field.label }} 
{% if field.field.required %}<em>*</em>{% endif %}</label>
```

it is not functional as field label id would different than field label, as "name" not "Name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very similar to [this Django snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/474/).  A comment there suggests using:

```
    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">
```

instead of your:

```
    <label for="id_{{ field.label }}">
```

You can also try [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/693/) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**template:**

```
<label for="{{ user_form.first_name.id_for_label }}" class="{{ user_form.first_name.css_classes }}">{{ user_form.first_name.label }}{{ user_form.label_suffix }}</label>
```

**forms.py:**

```
class UserChangeForm(DjangoUserChangeForm):
    error_css_class = 'field_error'
    required_css_class = 'field_required'
```

**CSS:**

```
.field_required:after {
    content: " *";
}
```